# Google maps loaded with error in javascript

Tags: javascript, cordova, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

i am new to javascript and have made a demo on google maps,Interesting thing for me is i have made demo in v2 and then changed it to google maps api v3 with just changing url.So now my map is loading successfully but with the following error.
**log**

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '__e3ae_' of undefinedS.trigger @ js?sensor=false&v=3.5&_=1449578432459:42appCinico.onSuccess @ index.js:449
```

my code is as below:

**index.html**

```
 function init()
            {
                console.log("I am here");
                var mapOption = {
//                    center: latLong,
                    zoom: 10,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                    disableDefaultUI: true
                };
                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOption);
            }
            function loadScript() {
                $.ajax({
                   // url: 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyADAgC6Payul6axiClP_z1stx8lBY2pUyE&callback=init',
                   url : 'http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&v=3.5',
                    dataType: 'script',
                    timeout: 300,
                    success: function () {
//                        alert("success:");
                    },
                    error: function () {
//                        alert("error:");
                    }
                });

            }
```

Comment: `success: function () {
   init()
},`
google.maps object won't be available before success

Comment: @aishwatsingh-Som what code changes should;, i make for this?

Comment: originall u had `url: 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyADAgC6Payul6axiClP_z1stx8lBY2pUyE&callback=init',` which loads javascript and calls init function , but now u r loading script from ajax so, after script is loaded u can use google.maps that's y , just replace `success` part and call `init` in success callback

Comment: And also sometimes my map markers not loaded.

Comment: ok, now r u able to get map atleast ? for marker refer https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-simple

Comment: @aishwatsingh- map was loaded already brother,but fires an error in console.!!!